# How to pass the output of a powershell script to a pythonscript

Tags: python, powershell, winrm

I am using python winrm protocol to run a Powershell script in the windows server.When I run the script as standalone in the server, the script output is getting displayed fine whereas when i call the script from python, the output is empty. Suggestions please.

Python : std_out, std_err, status_code = p.get_command_output(shell_id, command_id)
         print(std_out.decode('utf-8'))
Powershell : write-output - "#START $output #END"

The output returned from powershell is that of a Java Jar output.

Comment: to me, the simplest solution is to write the info out to a JSON file & then import it into the python script.

Comment: Could you please brief your answer on how do I import the Json into the python script? Thanks

Comment: i see that the problem was at the source. glad to know that you found & fixed it ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was errors being thrown in the jar output and hence the output was not capturing it. When std_err, status_code were decoded to utf-8(like i did with std_out print(std_out.decode('utf-8'))), i was able to see the results.